# Accessibility Identifier issue in ReactNative

Tags: android, ios, react-native, accessibility

I am setting accessibility identifier for my components in react native using `testID` in iOS and `accessibilityLabel` in android. For iOS is working fine but for Android it my identifier is appended with `,` (a comma and a space). I am not sure what is causing issue. Here is my code:

```
const renderAccessibilityLabel = (str) => {
  const propsForAutomation = {};
  if (Platform.OS === "ios") {
    propsForAutomation.testID = str;
  } else {
    propsForAutomation.accessibilityLabel = str;
  }
  return propsForAutomation;
};

// Inside render method:
<Text {...renderAccessibilityLabel("MyText")}>{MyText}</Text>
```

result > ios: `MyText`
android: `MyText,`

I don't know whats wrong with code :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[There was a bug](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/25581) with react native that was fixed in 0.60.5.

My guess is you are using an earlier version (0.60), updating will correct this.

Problem occurs in `ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/uimanager/BaseViewManager.java`

Line 178 `contentDescription.append(accessibilityLabel + ", ");`

Just in case you can't update for any reason, it can be fixed by adding `contentDescription = contentDescription.replaceAll(", $", "");` just above the line `if (contentDescription.length() > 0) {`

Or by replacing the file with the changes in https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/812abfd.